# Heuristics for a variant of the traveling salesman problem

Tags: reference-request, heuristics, traveling-salesman

I am looking at a variant of TSP in which rather than visiting every node, there is a given collection of (possibly overlapping) subset, and the salesman must pass through one node from each subset.

Concretely, I have a graph with vertices $V$ and a family of subsets $S = \{S_1, S_2, ..., S_n \}$. I'm looking for a simple path $\{(v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_3), ..., (v_{m}, v_{1})\}$ such that for all $S_i$, there is a $k$ such that $v_k \in S_i$.

I'm interested in approximation algorithms, and heuristics for computing lower bounds for partial solutions for use in a branch and bound computation. Has this problem been studied elsewhere? If it helps, the problem is metric and the graph is complete.

Comment: The closest thing I've found so far is [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0968090X15000844?casa_token=Lwvis9Jn9jYAAAAA:5eQkUtpm_7lR8A86XEkqNkKne0HI8YaZLTKWbU_DsIa9rc05TOLHVLfsqG-aDBSIOTj88OQ) paper, but it's still quite a bit different from this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is known as the [Generalized TSP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_TSP_problem).